# Is there a reason behind the number of badges owned by John Doe in the tour page?

Tags: support, badges, tour

When we take a [tour](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tour) of any Stack Exchange site, we are shown some basic info about questions, answers, tags etc., in the form of slides. We are also shown a slide about the reputation. Here an anonymous account of John Doe is shown. John has the same reputation and badges across the network.

As you can see below, there are 3 gold, 22 silver and 74 bronze badges:

> [image]

Is there any logic behind the stats of John Doe?  Is it some kind of magic figure or just a random example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's (probably) a random, and rather poor example. It is practically impossible to get a hundred badges with such a low reputation, unless you give a lot of reputation away with bounties. Most users with those kind of badge stats have a reputation ranging from 2-10k (on Stack Overflow, according to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/721788/reputation-for-users-with-100-badges)).

Thanks @rene for the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/721784), showing that there *are* indeed such users. Some of them have a lot of Popular and Notable Questions without much reputation, which (generally speaking) means they have commonly occurring problems but aren't really good at writing great questions about them. Also, as @IlmariKaronen notices, they lost some of their rep by placing bounties. While those clearly have their uses, they aren't the model users Stack Exchange is looking for.

Another exception to this rule of thumb are users who are very active Meta participants, like [Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra?tab=profile) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: I already mentioned the bounties.

Comment: " they aren't the model users Stack Exchange is looking for" May I know which type of users are considered as model users?

Comment: [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: All the users returned by @rene's query have given away at least 1k (and some of them up to 8k) rep in bounties. The sawtooth-shaped rep graph is a dead giveaway.

Comment: Ps. The bug in your original query is that you're only listing users with *exactly* 100 badges, not those with *at least* 100 badges. Users with low rep and lots of badges are rare to begin with, so artificially limiting the result set like that has a good chance of missing them all.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that's by design (though for smaller sites, it's probably better to work with a bandwidth of, say, 95-105). Otherwise, users like e.g. Jon Skeet would skew the results too much.

Comment: model users? Jon skeet? who's this Jon Skeet?