# On which site was the default example question in the tour page asked?

Tags: support, tour, unicorns

When we take tour of a new beta site, we are shown a question "How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies?". For example try [Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour). Is this a real question asked by users or a question created by the developers to show as an example?  If this is a real question, on which site did Unicorns eat daisies?

On a side note, it is a big coincidence that the user posted the question and users posted answers have exactly the same gravatar.

Comment: Interesting name.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's an intentionally made-up question that exists only in the `/tour` page.

First, unicorn is a fantasy creature that does not really exist in this world.

Second, given the tags on that question, it should have been closed as *unclear what you're asking* very quickly.

Third, all the users have the same avatar, as you've noted.

Conclusion: Made-up question.

Comment: Yes, I too believe it is for example purpose. I also asked about [John Doe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300766/357396) in the tour page. Not sure he is real or not. I will wait till some Dev responds. They may confirm.